# Fetch Airtable cell content with python using an identifier - why is use of identifier not working?

Tags: python, airtable

I have created the python script below - but specific cells cannot be fetched (not found - error)- however if all fields are fetched it works. I am using URL parameter like https://fundfox-9390e4999b31.herokuapp.com/result?submission_id=3

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def loading():
    return render_template('loading.html')

@app.route('/result')
def result():
    
    submission_id = request.args.get('submission_id')  
    airtable_url = f"https://api.airtable.com/v0/apptIx6sSgAbZaIV8/fundfox/{submission_id}"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer XXXXXXXXX"
    }
    response = requests.get(airtable_url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()

    
    desired_field_content = data.get('fields', {}).get('submission_id', 'No results')
    
    

    
    print("Submission ID:", submission_id)
    print("Airtable Response:", data)
    print("Response Status Code:", response.status_code)
    return render_template('result.html', desired_field=desired_field_content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If I adjust the code and fetch all fields I get a result (all fields are displayed) -

```
    response = requests.get(airtable_url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()

    # Extract all fields
    fields = data.get('fields', {})
```

This is how the airtable looks like -

[image]

What am I missing?

- I changed the row format in Airtable for `submission_id` row
- Adjusted the code multiple times

Answer (score 0):

The airtable_url was not set up correctly - I managed it now by using filterByFormula -

[https://api.airtable.com/v0/apptIx6sSgAbZaIV8/fundfox?filterByFormula=({{submission_id}}={submission_id})](https://api.airtable.com/v0/apptIx6sSgAbZaIV8/fundfox?filterByFormula=(%7B%7Bsubmission_id%7D%7D=%7Bsubmission_id%7D))